# Using Block Ending Early

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have method like this:

```
public async Task DoStuff(){
    //stuff
    using(var DisposableThing=DisposableThingProvider.GetThing()){
        foreach(var A in AList){
            foreach(var B in A){
                if(!await B.GetBoolAsync()){
                    //Error Stuff
                }
                else{
                    //Different Stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if B.GetBoolAsync() is false, program execution jumps to the end of the using statement.
B.GetBoolAsync() does not cause an exception.
//Error Stuff Executes before jumping out of both foreach statements.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you executing multiple `DoStuff` concurrently (or recursively from `GetBoolAsync`)?

Comment: show the code that calls `DoStuff()`

Comment: You need to show your real code, or at least a simple, working set of code that *reproduces* your problem.  The code you're showing isn't the problem.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/BenjaminHolland/2a7f8486c6251ced342a#file-gistfile1-cs-L1

Comment: All the information here was very good, but it turned out to be a really, REALLY stupid mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to access a variable you're iterating on without waiting for that iteration to return.  The value of A is changing before A.GetBoolAsync is returning.  This causes a race condition between the iterator and the return value.

IEnumerable are not threadsafe in this manner - check out Jon Skeet's [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/10/23/iterating-atomically.aspx) on how to handle this.

On a seperate note, you should probably structure your code differently so the error condition is in the else, like

```
if(await B.GetBoolAsync()){
    //Different Stuff
}
else{
    //Error Stuff
}
```

Comment: thread execution should halt until the async operation completes due to the await, so how does B get a new value when the iteration's block contains the await statement?

Comment: From the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx): An await expression does not block the thread on which it is executing. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the async method as a continuation on the awaited task. Control then returns to the caller of the async method. When the task completes, it invokes its continuation, and execution of the async method resumes where it left off.

Comment: correct, but execution of the method itself is halted

Comment: returning control to the caller is outside the scope of this method - how does var `B` get a new value prior to the completion of the async call to `B.GetBoolAsync()`?

Comment: @Moho what is happening that is causing this race condition, then?

Comment: I can't spot the problem with @ginkner code, unless he's executing multiple `DoStuff` concurrently. He didn't say he is.

Answer (score 1):

Demo'd to be working properly - no race condition.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var task = DoStuff();

        Console.WriteLine( "Calling thread returned control to caller" );

        Task.WaitAll( task );

        Console.WriteLine( "Aync method call completed" );

        Console.ReadLine();
    } 

    public static async Task DoStuff()
    {
        var items = new List<TestA>()
        {
            new TestA() { Id = 10 },
            new TestA() { Id = 20 },
            new TestA() { Id = 30 },
        };

        foreach( var ta in items )
        {
            ta.Bs.Add( new TestB() { Id = 1 } );
            ta.Bs.Add( new TestB() { Id = 2 } );
            ta.Bs.Add( new TestB() { Id = 3 } );
        }

        using( var db = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection() )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Entered 'using'" );

            foreach( var a in items )
            {
                foreach( var b in a.Bs )
                {
                    if( !await b.GetBoolAsync() )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( "{0}: false", a.Id + b.Id );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( "{0}: true", a.Id + b.Id );
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine( "Leaving 'using'");
        }

        Console.WriteLine( "Left 'using'");
    }
}

public class TestA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<TestB> Bs { get; set; }

    public TestA()
    {
        Bs = new List<TestB>();
    }
}

public class TestB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public async Task<bool> GetBoolAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);

        return Convert.ToBoolean( this.Id % 2 );
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]